# Conditional Tag for Outlook 365

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I am building a HTML Newsletter.

To specifically target all Outlook Versions lesser or equal than Outlook 2013, we may use this code:

```
<!--[if lte mso 15]>                            
    code goes here
<![endif]-->
```

Here, 15 refers to Outlook 2013's version number.

What's the conditional tag for Outlook 365?

How would I specifically target Outlook 365 as opposed to any future Outlook versions, if and when they may come?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the greater-than or equal operator (gte) rather then the less than. (lte)

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]> 
    <style>
        /* Target Outlook 2007 and up */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Here's a list of the [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Syntax) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your comments read in outlook 365, try inserting 3-9 empty "sacrificial" comments below the head or in the body. I noticed this behavior worked when I realized that my later conditional comments were operating, while my earlier conditional comments were being destroyed and found a reference talking about adding 3 comments. I needed to add more than three, like I said... but I have passed litmus tests just fine with only adding 3 in some cases (e.g. only one conditional comment in the document). Since I used the same gte comments for ol '13 and above I'm not quite sure which ones you need to target Outlook specifically, but you will be able to better narrow down the correct commenting if you can actually get them to show up and pare down from there.

The correct answer might be a gte mso $foo targeting several versions however, since Outlook365 behavior probably depends in some convoluted way upon the user agent and os of the client accessing it... i.e. IE 9-11, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc... OSX/PC...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to target specific versions of Outlook past 2016.

Everything after Outlook 2016 is still `mso 16`.

See [How to target Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019 separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707631/how-to-target-outlook-2016-and-outlook-2019-separately)