# How to target Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019 separately

Tags: outlook, ms-office

Is there any way in which I can target Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019 separately? I want to apply certain styles for Outlook 2019 only, and not for Outlook 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional logic like the following one:

```
Outlook 2013    <!--[if mso 15]> your code <![endif]-->
Outlook 2016    <!--[if mso 16]> your code <![endif]-->
```

Read more about that in the [Outlook conditional CSS](https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso) article.

Comment: Actually he cannot use the conditional rendering. Outlook 2013 = mso 15, but Outlook 2016, Outlook 2019, and Office 365 desktop = mso 16

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. Outlook 2019 version is still 16.x.x.x. It is essentially Outlook 2016 forked from 2016 in early 2019. Office 365 versions of Outlook are actually newer than 2019.

Why exactly do you need to do that?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am building an Outlook Web Add-In which behaves differently on Outlook 2016 and 2019 clients. Because of that I need to show some element on one and hide it on another. Not easily? Does that mean there is a way?